# Not able to update the contents of a Tcl file created from a Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, tcl

I have coded a Makefile which has a target to create a tcl file and I want to update the contents of the contents of the tcl file from the Makefile but the contents of the tcl file is not updated as expected. The code written is as below:

The abc.mk file has FILE_ARGS which has the string `select[file_tpye=txt]`

Inside Makefile

```
.SILENT:
include ./abc.mk

FILE_ARGS_NEW = $(shell echo $(FILE_ARGS) | sed 's/\[/\\[;s/\]/\\]/')

FILE_TCL="\
set FILE_ARGS_NEW \"$(FILE_ARGS_NEW)\" \n \
...

all: def.tcl

def.tcl : 
     echo -e $(FILE_TCL) > def.tcl
```

When I run `make all` expectation is that it should create a def.tcl and inside this file the contents should be

```
set FILE_ARGS_NEW "select\\[file_tpye=txt\\]"
```

but now def.tcl has the contents as below:

```
set FILE_ARGS_NEW ""
```

Comment: Please edit your question to make appropriate use of the StackOverflow formatting facilities, such as code blocks etc.  It's very hard to understand your question without proper formatting.

Comment: Also please show the exact contents of `abc.mk` where `FILE_ARGS` is set.

Comment: Also please show the output that make generates when you run the make command.

Comment: ... That is, the output it produces after you have removed or commented out `SILENT:`.

Comment: Right.  You should never add `.SILENT` or `@` to your makefile until AFTER it's completely working.  Else it's like redirecting the output of your program to `/dev/null` then asking what is wrong with it.

Comment: Also, I don't know what the `...` in your makefile means.  One thing I'll say right off, is that `echo -e` is completely non-portable.  You should never use `echo` in any portable script (such as a makefile recipe) to do anything other than print simple text.  If you need anything more fancy, use `printf` instead of `echo`.

Comment: @MadScientist
Sorry for the incomplete description
abc.mk has below contents:
FILE_ARGS = select[file_tpye=txt]
and ... means some extra code.

Comment: The reason I ask about `...` is that there's no ending double-quote in the `FILE_TCL` variable assignment in your example, so we have no idea what is going on there.  In general it's very, very unusual to create a makefile like this, just as it's very unusual to use the `shell` function like this.  But to solve your problem follow the advice given above: remove the `.SILENT` target so you can see what make is running.  If that doesn't help you, edit your question (don't use comments!!) and add in that output, properly formatted, so we can see it.